# CaslJS with ESM Node16

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, casl

I've been using CaslJS (@casl/ability) for a few years now and am now trying to migrate my typescript project from CommonJS to ESM.

I've got my whole project migrated, but CaslJS throws errors about missing declaration files, e.g.:

```
node_modules/@casl/ability/dist/types/types.d.ts(1,32): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@ucast/mongo2js'.
```

I've done a bit of digging into this, and isolated the problem to the `"moduleResolution": "node16"` configuration in `tsconfig.json`.

With this set to `node` the project builds fine (but the build produces commonjs, not esm)

Any help with fixing these type errors would be appreciated as Casl is now the only blocker to moving to ESM.

I've been able to replicate this in a new example project here: https://github.com/egmacke/rush-examples/tree/master/casljs-esm-node16

Comment: Hello Ed. Were you able to solve this issue ? I am facing the exact same situation, with ability6.3.3, trying to migrate my project to ES module.

Comment: @keuluu This has now been resolved - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470125/2064380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved. The issue was actually with the `@ucast/mongo2js` library not exporting it's types correctly.

For reference, https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/734